# Number of ways to climb N stairs with 1,2 and 3 stairs at a time with a condition that you can climb 3 stairs at a time only k times?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am doing competitive programming. I faced a problem with a question in which we need to find the number of ways to climb A stairs with 1,2 and 3 steps at a time. I solved this part using dynamic programming. The question has an additional condition too. That is we can jump 3 stairs only B times. I have attached my code. How do I solve this new part?

```
A = int(input())
B= int(input())
f = [1,2]
for i in range(3,A+1):
    if B>0:
        if i==3:
            f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2]+1)
        else:
            f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2]+f[i-3])
        B-=1
    else:
        f.append(f[i-1]+f[i-2])
print(f[-1])


Test case:
A=4
B=1
Output expected=7
I got 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using dynamic-programming. Below is breakdown of the process.

Let `f(n,k)` denote the number of ways of climbing `n` stairs with 1, 2 or 3 stairs at a time, but using *at most* `k` 3-steps.

Given `n` and `k`, we have three possibilities:

- First step is a 1-step. We can climb remaining in `f(n-1,k)` ways.
- First step is a 2-step. We can climb remaining in `f(n-2,k)` ways.
- First step is a 3-step. We can climb remaining in `f(n-3,k-1)` ways.

So, we obtain the recurrence `f(n,k) = f(n-1,k) + f(n-2,k) + f(n-3,k-1)` for all `n>=3`.

The base cases will be `f(0,j) = f(1,j) = 1` and `f(2,j) = 2` for all `0<=j<=k`.

Below is the corresponding code in C++:

```
int f(int n, int k) {

    if(n<2) return 1;
    if(n==2) return 2;

    // dp is a 2D array of n+1 rows and k+1 cols
    // dp[i][j] stores the result f(i,j)

    vector<vector<int> > dp(n+1, vector<int>(k+1,0));

    for(int j=0; j<=k; j++){
        dp[0][j] = dp[1][j] = 1;
        dp[2][j] = 2;
    }

    for(int i=3; i<=n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=k; j++){

            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] + dp[i-2][j];
            if(j>0) {
                dp[i][j] += dp[i-3][j-1];
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[n][k];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the code? I don't know C++ so I am having difficulty understanding it.

Comment: @DhruvSingh The first line declares a function `f(n,k)`. And that `vector<vector<int> > ...` line is used to declare a 2D array, named `dp`, having `(n+1)` rows and `(k+1)` columns whose all entries are initially zero. I think rest is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to add a dimension to the state description: "given how many steps you need to do and how many triple jumps you are allowed to do, how many different ways there are to climb the staircase?"

You cannot use just a single array for the problem, you need a 2D matrix with number of steps on one dimension and number of triple jumps in the other.

The the decomposition in subproblems is simple: when you do a 1/2 jump you just decrease the first index accordingly by either 1 or 2, when you do a triple jump (if allowed) you decrease the first by three and the second by one.

Written in the recursive/memoized version the code becomes (Python):

```
def ways(A, B): 
    if A < 3: 
        return max(A, 1) 
    try: 
        return cache[A, B] 
    except KeyError: 
        n = ways(A-1, B) + ways(A-2, B) 
        if A > 2 and B > 0: 
            n += ways(A-3, B-1) 
        cache[A, B] = n 
        return n
```